# React-query typescript useInfiniteQuery

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-query

```
export function fetchRandomVideos({ pageParam = 1 }) {
  return Request.get<PaginatedResponseBody<TRandomVideo>>(
    endpoints.RANDOM_VIDEOS,
    {
      params: {
        page: pageParam,
        per_page: 10
      }
    }
  );
}

export function useRandomVideosQuery() {
  return useInfiniteQuery('randomVideos', fetchRandomVideos, {
    getNextPageParam: (lastPageData: PaginatedResponseBody<TRandomVideo>) => {
      console.log(lastPageData);
      return lastPageData.data.next_page_url;
    }
  });
}
```

[image]

I don't know what's wrong with `useInfiniteQuery`.

packages:
"typescript": "4.7.2",
"react-query": "^3.39.1",
"next": "12.1.6",
"react": "^18.1.0",
"react-dom": "^18.1.0",

Comment: Please also use actual code not simply a picture of code (picture is OK for a visual but also include the code being used so we may best assist you in fixing it and not mistype something trying to read it

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss Code added

Comment: You might need to call the function in order to return the underlying promise. Try `fetchRandomVideos()` instead of `fetchRandomVideos`

Answer (score 0):

`fetchRandomVideos` seems to be a function that returns a function, not a function that returns a Promise. Hard to say more without knowing what `Request.get` returns.

Maybe start with explicitly annotating the function return value, then you will see the error in a better location:

```
export function fetchRandomVideos({ pageParam = 1 }): Promise<PaginatedResponseBody<TRandomVideo>> {
```

with that signature, react-query will be happy, but likely you'll see an error inside the function now.

Answer (score -1):

```
export function useRandomVideosQuery() {
  return useInfiniteQuery(
    ['randomVideos'],
    ({ pageParam }) => fetchRandomVideos({ pageParam })(),
    {
      getNextPageParam: (lastPageData) => lastPageData?.data.next_page_url
    }
  );
}
```

Comment: Can you add the explanation around the snippet as well?